# Jslider execute code on change

Tags: jquery, jslider

I am using a theme with Jslider [this](http://preview.byaviators.com/drupal/carat/category-car/carcategory/extended-length-suv) (bottom right corner).

I want the jslider.change to hide all the divs with data-price outside the range.

For this I have constructed this function:

```
function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
$("#carlist div.row-item").hide().filter(function() {
var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
}).show();
}
```

With the normal Jquery range slider i can trigger that via the   slide: function(event, ui) command. How can i trigger it via jslider ?

In Jquery range slider i would use

```
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                 var mi = ui.values[ 0 ];
                var mx = ui.values[ 1 ];
                filterSystem(mi, mx);
           }
```

Kind thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the slider's documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".selector").slider({
    onstatechange: function( value ){
        console.dir( value );
    }
});
```